# phalcon - insert data through loop is not working

Tags: php, mysql, model, phalcon, phalcon-routing

I'm trying to save data in phalcon framework using model. My actual goal to loop through the array and insert them using that loop. But problem is it's always inserting the last value of the array.

```
Example: $tags = [1,2,3,4]
```

But when I execute the code it's inserting only 4 in the database.

```
       //grab the tag model
        $tagModel = new Tags();


        //loop through the tag array
        foreach($tags as $tag){

            $tagModel->tag_name = $tag;
            $tagModel->save();
        }
```

Is there any solution for this issue?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$tagModel` is linked to a single entry in the database, so you create an entry in the 1st itteration, then update it in the rest.

To fix simply create a new instance of Tags() each itteration:

```
//loop through the tag array
foreach($tags as $tag){
    $tagModel = new Tags();
    $tagModel->tag_name = $tag;
    $tagModel->save();
}
```

Comment: I found the solution just after posted the question. Forgot submit the answer. Thanks for your help